# Workbench returning Heroku application error when trying to download bulk api job results

Tags: soql, bulk-api, workbench

I ran a bulk csv job via Workbench (workbench.developerforce.com), and it appears to have run successfully.  There are two files to download, one (the second one) downloads fine but the first one returns a generic Heroku application error.  Any ideas?  The other day, I was able to download both files from a job.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Could you add some specific details or screenshots? [About the error, may be a sample csv that you uploaded etc.]

Comment: @arut I didn't upload a csv, I ran a SELECT query using the bulk csv option.  There are a lot of records, so the job ended up with two CSV files to download.  The first file doesn't download - instead it spins for a while and then results in the generic "Application Error".  The second file downloads just fine.  I'll get a screenshot of the error, but here's the text: Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Comment: so, the generic application error doesn't give out much details. Were you able to check the logs (as mentioned in the error)?

Comment: This isn't my heroku instance - this is workbench.developerforce.com.

Comment: This is quite a generic error. I haven't come across this in the past. In the error page, is "check you logs for details" a hyperlink? If yes, then have you clicked on it to see if there are any instruction to get hold of logs to see what is going on here.

Comment: Yes, it is a generic error.  It is a hyperlink, but it's just for the Heroku documentation on how to utilize logging in your Heroku app.

Comment: What is the record count on the query result? Are there any text area type fields in the query? I can try to replicate this problem at my end if you can give me me some details.

Comment: There are approx 7.5 million records - here's an anonymous version of the query:
SELECT CreatedDate,
CustomField1Boolean__c,
CustomField2Text255__c,
CustomField3Text255__c,
CustomField3LookupToAcct__c,
FirstName,
Id,
LastModifiedDate,
LastName,
PersonEmail,
Phone,
RecordTypeId,
X18_Digit_Id__c 
FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeId = '<id for person account record type>'

I've figured out another workaround, so any more focus on this is really just for my curiosity.

Comment: OK. I doubt if the text field values are the ones causing this problem. Did you try the same SOQL (minus the text fields)?

Comment: If anybody else sees this, it just happened to me a couple times and then resolved itself ten minutes later (i.e. I could still click on the download links and they still worked).